# The text inside canvas still persists even after clearRect()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So what I did basically was adding a delete button from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22792428/5467952) answer to clear the canvas' content.

HTML:

```
<button id="delete">delet this</button><br>
```

JS:

```
$("#delete").click(function () {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});
```

It works as intended until I realize it wasn't: if I click the Draw Text button, the text that was supposedly gone appeared again. Anybody knows why?

The fiddle in question: http://jsfiddle.net/wgq384et/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you clear the canvas, you don't clear the array texts[]. So when you redraw, it redraw stored texts.
Simply add `texts=[];` to your delete button onclick method

Comment: or `texts.length = 0`

Comment: Yup, this is confirmed to do the trick. Thank you very much. So actually when I click the draw button, it's not actually drawing from the textbox, but rather from the array that contains the text from the textbox, is that correct?